# Convert word to another substituting case (upper or lower) with same case

Tags: regular-expression, substitute, letter-case

I am looking for a way to convert one word to another while "capturing" the case of the match that is substituted. An example:

I have the text:

> Begin the beginning

Now I want to convert this to

> End the ending

To do so I need a command like the one below:

```
s/([Bb]egin/ [CASE OF CAPTURE][Ee]nd/g
```

But then with a correctly working `[CASE OF CAPTURE][Ee]` part.

How do we get the case of the capture (being upper or lowercase begin) and substitute with same (upper or lowercase end)?

Comment: From stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/q/782511/4751065

Comment: @SakariCajanus Thank you. I see that without a plugin it is quite cumbersome. Guess I have to find out how to use plugins in ViEmu.

Comment: I understand it's just an example, but sometimes you might just want to do 2 substitutions instead of one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
:s/\([Bb]\)egin/\=printf("%snd", submatch(1)==#'B'?'E':'e')/
```

This checks in the replacement part of the `:s` command, what the case of the first subgroup was and either returns an upper 'e' or a lower 'e'.

Comment: And a `/g` at the end ;). Note that "Begin of the beginning" turns into "End of the endning", but that was my mistake. Thank you. :)